# AWS Trust Policy Clarification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

How are trust policies assumed by AWS Services exactly. The documentation is melting my brain— follow this link, follow that link in circles.

Can someone end the suffering and just tell me that how, from my terminal, if I have admin permissions configured, how can I force an AWS service to assume a trust policy.

For example, if I update a CloudFormation stack with the AWS CLI using `aws cloudformation deploy args`, how do I ensure that cloudformation is assuming the trust policy's permissions that I've configured for it and not my the immediate credentials I am currently using?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AWS CloudFormation Service Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html):

> To associate a service role with a stack, specify the role when you create the stack.

When creating a stack in the management console or via `aws cloudformation create-stack`, you should specify `--role-arn`. All operations on the stack will then use the Role, not your own credentials.

If you stack is already created, `update-stack --role-arn` can be used. From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html):

> AWS CloudFormation uses the role's credentials to make calls on your behalf. AWS CloudFormation always uses this role for all future operations on the stack.